# How select values where all columns are null for particular ID, ID is not unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with following format and I want to get the  LotId if Value1 is null for all the rows.

Now If I am doing Select,
`Select * from Table1 where Value1 IS nul`l , I am getting back a row .

But I want nothing should be returned as there are two rows which have some value.

I thought of self join , but this can have n number of rows.

```
Id          LotId       Value1      
-------------------------------------------------
1       LOt0065          NULL       
2       LOt0065          SomeValue
3       LOt0065          SomeValue
```

Comment: I have a doubt, what you want in result, value1 haing null or value1 having some value

Comment: @PramodYadav, in result I want Valu1 does not have any value in any of the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use an EXISTS subquery here:

```
SELECT a.lotid
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table1 b
  WHERE b.lotid = a.lotid
  AND b.value1 IS NOT NULL
);
```

If my syntax is right, then this will show you all records that don't have any NULL values for that lotid:

- It uses a SELECT 1 because the subquery doesn't need to show any value, it just needs to match on the outer query.
- You compare the table in the inner query to the table in the outer query and match on the common field you're looking at (lotid in this case)
- This could also be done with a NOT IN clause.

Does this give you the result you want?